# Android connection.getInputStream() return FileNotFoundException Error

Tags: android

I'm trying to implementing simple download manager for my application on android, i use simple `Serivce` to download file from internet and when i use this method for create connection:

```
private HttpURLConnection createConnection(String urlStr) throws IOException {
    URL               url  = new URL(urlStr);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setReadTimeout(timeout);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
    return conn;
}
```

i don't get any exception and work fine for this link:

```
https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png
```

now i want to get `getInputStream()` from connection and assign variable as:

in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream(), BUFFER_SIZE);

but i get this error:

```
'java.io.FileNotFoundException' exception.
```

i can get file length fine from connection but i can't download that

```
   new Thread(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           try {
               prepareDownload(fileUrl, filePath, lastModified);
               connection = createConnection(fileUrl);
               fileDownloadStatus = downloadStatus.DOWNLOADING;
               if (!startNewDownload) {
                   connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + downloadedFile.length() + "-");
               }
               if (onDownloadProcess != null)
                   onDownloadProcess.fileLength(fileLength);
               in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream(), BUFFER_SIZE);
               long progressLength = 0;
               if (!startNewDownload) {
                   progressLength += downloadedFile.length();
                   // append to exist downloadedFile
                   writer = new FileOutputStream(filePath, true);
               } else {
                   writer = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
                   // save remote last modified data to local
                   lastModified = connection.getHeaderField("Last-Modified");
               }
               try {
                   byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                   int    count;
                   while (getFileDownloadStatus() == downloadStatus.DOWNLOADING && (count = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                       progressLength += count;
                       writer.write(buffer, 0, count);
                       // progress....
                       if (onDownloadProcess != null)
                           onDownloadProcess.onProgress((int) (progressLength * 100 / fileLength));
                       if (progressLength == fileLength) {
                           progressLength = 0;
                           setFileDownloadStatus(downloadStatus.COMPLETE);
                       }
                   }
               ...
   }).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

First I see that you use HttpConnection for a `https` URL.
You receive FileNotFound if the request fails (can not find the specified file). It might well be because of that.

Here is a snippet from a WebRequest class I use in my apps, it works fine for all https downloads

```
        URL url = new URL(request);

        con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        con.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
        con.setUseCaches(false);

        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(postData);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        // those are from my class to return the server response
        result.setResultCode(con.getResponseCode());
        result.setResultMessage(con.getResponseMessage());

        InputStream stream = con.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
```

This is for html requests (reading until the end of text) but I think you can use the properties I set on `con` for your image download too.

Comment: problem dont resolve and i get this error for each http, https urls